# Iterate over string with commas

Tags: python, string

I have two strings:

```
x = 'a1,a2,a3'
y = 'b1,b2,b3'
```

I want to concatenate these two string as:

```
z = ['a1b1','a1b2','a1b3','a2b1','a2b2','a2b3','a3b1','a3b2','a3b3']
```

I used the code snippet:

```
for i in x:
     for j in y:
         z.append(i+j)
```

But the result was not as required. How can I obtain the required result?

Comment: The actual **problem** here was with splitting the input strings - while `itertools.product` is the right tool for producing the cartesian product, the approach was fine except for the part where iterating *over the individual strings* doesn't do what's needed. This was therefore closed with completely the wrong duplicate. The question is about how to treat the string `'a1,a2,a3'` as though it contained three strings `'a1'`, `'a2'`, `'a3'`; and that is a duplicate of the question about **how to split strings**. I have fixed this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)split the strings on `","`, then you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get the cartesian product of the two lists:

```
from itertools import product

x = "a1,a2,a3"
y = "b1,b2,b3"

print([fst + snd for fst, snd in product(x.split(","), y.split(","))])
# ['a1b1', 'a1b2', 'a1b3', 'a2b1', 'a2b2', 'a2b3', 'a3b1', 'a3b2', 'a3b3']
```

You could also do this nested loops in a list comprehension to achieve the same result:

```
print([fst + snd for fst in x.split(",") for snd in y.split(",")])
# ['a1b1', 'a1b2', 'a1b3', 'a2b1', 'a2b2', 'a2b3', 'a3b1', 'a3b2', 'a3b3']
```

Or use a solution similar to your original approach:

```
z = []
for fst in x.split(","):
    for snd in y.split(","):
        z.append(fst + snd)

print(z)
# ['a1b1', 'a1b2', 'a1b3', 'a2b1', 'a2b2', 'a2b3', 'a3b1', 'a3b2', 'a3b3']
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what you are looking for.

```
x = 'a1,a2,a3'.split(',')
y = 'b1,b2,b3'.split(',')


[a+b for a in x for b in y]
```

Comment: Simplest, and hence is the best.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `starmap` on the `product` with the `add` operator for that

```
from operator import add
from itertools import starmap, product
x = 'a1,a2,a3'
y = 'b1,b2,b3'
z=list(starmap(add, product(x.split(','),y.split(','))))
```

Answer (score 1):

A very straitghfoward method would be

```
x = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
y = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']

[(i+j) for i in x for j in y]

#['a1b1', 'a1b2', 'a1b3', 'a2b1', 'a2b2', 'a2b3', 'a3b1', 'a3b2', 'a3b3']
```